# React build and backend Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am developing an application using React and Express.js. I define static in React and build my back end using the code below, but when I make a get request, the following error is displayed in the client console. What can I do?

```
app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "../../build/index.html"));
});
```

// Backend API router

```
app.use("/api", router);
```

Client-side error message

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73787103/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider deploying React code using [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), and do a port forwarding within nginx to the backend APIs.

Comment: How can I do it, can you send me a documentation, please?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0